# Login to ASP .NET MVC website under HTTPS using Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

I have some administrative methods under ASP .NET MVC website that is under https.

So it looks like

```
https://mysite.com/cms
```

and there are some actions like `CheckUsers`

My question is

Can we develop some external **Windows Service** to sign in to that website and execute some methods?

I mean how to do it technically (sign in and call methods?)

So tha chain is like that

> Windows Service <---> call method CheckUsers() under 
>   https://mysite.com/cms <---> other https://site2.com

I just need to automate execution of some methods and do it periodically with Windows Service.

It is a question of possible communication between Windows Service and ASP .NET MVC.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ for sending requests to third-party web sites. It allows you to send requests, receive response/status code/etc. Basically, its a small GUI-less browser which evaluates HTMKL, JavaScript, etc.

(it's a Java lib, so you could either google for a .Net port or use a converter to convert Java assembly into .Net assembly - see http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/ for guidance. We've used the convertion approach).

If your requirements are less sophisticated, you can just use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to send simple requests and parse responses manually.

NB: in case you're going to parse HTML manually, I suggest that you use [Html Afgility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/): this is the *right* way to parse HTML(mainly, because it "fixes" invalid tags, errors, etc).